# How does Windows know if there are 'known compatibility issues' with a program?

Tags: windows-7, compatibility

I've seen this dialog pop up from time to time when installing softwre and I was wondering how Windows knows about these issues. I'm working on making an application 'Compatible with Windows 7" and was wondering how I should go about making sure this dialog doesn't appear.

[image: This program has known compatibility issues]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple list of applications (or versions of applications) that PCA - Program Compatibility Assistant - checks. More [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756937.aspx).